# complete function space

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, continuity, banach-spaces

I am currently working on the following problem:

Let's consider the space $C^1([0,1])$ of the continuously differentiable functions on $[0,1]$

(a) Show that by $||f||:=|f(0)+\|f'\|_∞$ for all $f ∈ C^1 ([0,1])$ a norm on $C^1([0.1])$ is defined.

(b) Show that $(C^1([0.1]),||·||)$ is a Banach space.

For a) I wanted to show that
i) $||0||=0$ and $||x||>0$ if $0≠x∈C^1$
ii) $||r*x||=|r|*|x|$ for $x ∈ C^1, r ∈ ℝ$
iii) $||x+y||≤ ||x||+||y||$ for $x,y ∈ C^1$ applies

But I am not sure how to do it properly and if that's the only thing I need to show, in order to prove that it is a norm.

For b) I tried to use the idea that every Cauchy sequence must converge in C.

If you've got any idea on how to solve or approach it, I would be so happy to be hearing from you!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What have you tried? You have to be explicit about what part of the problem you can't solve, otherwise people won't answer this.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just edited my question. Could you help me now? @JustDroppedIn

Comment: you just wrote down the axioms of a norm. Yes that's what you need to show, but what did you try to do?

Comment: well, that's why I asked the question. I don't know how to show these axioms as I am a beginner. I tried for i) Say that $f=0, then ||0||=|0|+||0'||_∞=0+||0'||_∞=||0'||_∞=max{|0|}=0$ and if $f≠0$, then $||f||=|f(0)|+||f'||_∞ >0$ either because both parts are $>0$ as a $|x| always >0$ or because we look at $x ∈ f, x ∈ (0,1]$ but this sounds very stupid to me

Comment: For ii) I tried $||r*f||=|r*f(0)|+||r*f'||_∞=|r|*|f(0)|+|r|*||f||_∞=|r|*(|f(0)|+||f'||_∞)$ but then I got $|r|*||f||$ instead of $|r|*|f|$ so this is also stupid

Comment: for iii) I started with $||x+y||=|x(0)+y(0)|+||x'+y'||_∞$ but this already looks wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

a. Show that $||\cdot||$ is equivalent to the standard norm $||f||_s = \max \{||f||_\infty, ||f’||_\infty\}$. Then show that $||\cdot||_s$ is indeed a norm, if necessary.

b. Completeness follows from the theorem about term-by-term differentiation of functional sequences (or series, those two theorems are equivalent to each other).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! But I have a question...I'm sorry but I've never heard the word standard norm before, do you mean the euclidean-2-norm? because that's what I found on the internet. However, the definition of the 2-norm isn't max{||f||...} so I don't think this is what you meant. Or do you mean the Maximumsnorm? :(

Comment: Well, this is not some term, just a natural choice of a norm on $C^1$ which makes $C^1$ into a Banach space. The norm you’ve been given is also natural, since it is equivalent to $||\cdot||_s$, but you have to prove it first :)

Comment: so I only need to show that $||f||=|f(0)|+||f'||_∞$ is equivalent to $||f||_2=?$ and if it wasn't mentioned in our lecture yet, I show that $||f||_2$ define a norm?

Comment: Or do I need to take an $x ∈ f$, as I don't know how to define $||f||_2$

Comment: @Tinkerbell_ye yes, but don’t write $||\cdot||_2$ — the Euclidean norm is not the norm I used, and not even equivalent to it.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! So I need to show, that there exists $c_1,c_2>0$ with $c_1*||f||≤||f||_s≤c_2*||f|||$?

Comment: @Tinkerbell_ye yes, exactly